# I want to class my pivot table according to my other column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a data frame similar to mentioned below:

[image: Sample DataFrame]

And I need to get this type of table as the result:

`a.pivot_table(index=['DT'],columns=['TYPE'], values='AMOUNT',aggfunc=['count','sum','mean']).T`

where `a` is the actual data

[image]

I desire to get firstly comes TYPE after count, sum, mean.

Comment: was the answer helpful? If yes, I kindly request you to mark it as a verified answer as it would help others who might visit this page later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make use of `swaplevel` method of the multi indexed data frame as shown below:
[image]

```
a.pivot_table(index=['DT'],columns=['TYPE'], values='AMOUNT',aggfunc=['count','sum','mean']).T.swaplevel(0,1)
```

And your new data frame looks like this:

[image]